# Python schedule repeating multiple threads

Tags: python, multithreading, repeat

Well my problem is as follows. I have a script in which I want to run 3 functions each one in a different interval. All three share a resource. What I have done is the following (where res is the shared resource):

```
import threading
import thread

lock = threading.Lock()

def f1(res) :
  lock.acquire()
  # do stuff
  time = 10.0 # this one changes each time f1 runs
  lock.release()
  threading.Timer(time,f1).start()

def f2(res) :
  lock.acquire()
  # do stuff
  time = 8.0 # this one changes each time f2 runs
  lock.release()
  threading.Timer(time,f2).start()

def f3(res) :
  lock.acquire()
  # do stuff
  time = 8.0 # this one changes each time f3 runs
  lock.release()
  threading.Timer(time,f3).start()

thread.start_new_thread(f1(res))
thread.start_new_thread(f2(res))
thread.start_new_thread(f3(res))
```

When I execute the code what happens is that only the first thread (f1) executes forever and actually without waiting the time set in the Timer. Could someone please help by explaining to me what am I doing wrong and how can I make it right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?  Don't you need brackets after the function names?

Comment: I'm using 2.7. As for brackets see the updates. Forgot to add something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *When I execute the code what happens is that only the first thread (f1) executes forever and actually without waiting the time set in the
>   Timer.*

It sounds like the first thread is started, it spawns a new Timer thread, and there must be a `join` in there which is preventing the original thread from ending until its sub-thread is finished. Since that sub-thread spawns a sub-sub-thread, and so on, the original thread never ends.

The fact that only f1 executes might be because on this line

```
thread.start_new_thread(f1(res))
```

the inner argument `f1(res)` is evaluated before its return value is passed on to `thread.start_new_thread`. So you are actually *calling* `f1(res)` first from the main thread, not spawning a thread to call `f1`.

There is no need to use the `thread` module here. You can do everything you need with the high-level interface provided by the `threading` module. Moreover, the line

```
 thread.start_new_thread(f1(res))
```

raises a

```
TypeError: start_new_thread expected at least 2 arguments, got 1
```

so I'm not sure how you got your code to run...

Here is an alternative way to doing what (I think) you want.

```
import threading
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
lock = threading.Lock()

def f1():
    with lock:
        logger.info('f1')
        threading.Timer(10, f1).start()

def f2():
    with lock:
        logger.info('f2')
        threading.Timer(8, f2).start()

def f3():
    with lock:
        logger.info('f3')
        threading.Timer(23, f3).start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format='[%(asctime)s %(threadName)s] %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%H:%M:%S')
    threading.Thread(target=f1).start()
    threading.Thread(target=f2).start()
    threading.Thread(target=f3).start()
```

which prints something like:

```
[10:53:12 Thread-1] f1
[10:53:12 Thread-3] f2
[10:53:12 Thread-4] f3
[10:53:20 Thread-5] f2
[10:53:22 Thread-2] f1
[10:53:28 Thread-7] f2
[10:53:32 Thread-8] f1
[10:53:35 Thread-6] f3
[10:53:36 Thread-9] f2
  C-c C-\Quit
```

The timestamp shows f1 is run every 10 seconds, f2 every 8 seconds, and f3 every 23 seconds.

Comment: How can I re-use threads, instead of creating new threads for every time instant?

Answer (score 0):

The code below works for me. Are you sure the `#do stuff` in `f1` is not the culprit?

```
import threading
import thread

lock = threading.Lock()

def f1(res) :
    lock.acquire()
    print "F1"
    lock.release()
    threading.Timer(1.0,f1, [res]).start()

def f2(res) :
    lock.acquire()
    print "F2"
    lock.release()
    threading.Timer(2.0,f2, [res]).start()

def f3(res) :
    lock.acquire()
    print "F3"
    lock.release()
    threading.Timer(3.0,f3, [res]).start()

thread.start_new_thread(f1, (res,))
thread.start_new_thread(f2, (res,))
thread.start_new_thread(f3, (res,))
```

Comment: Could be only that the interval in which each thread I want to run is dynamic and comes from the #do stuff part of each function. Check the updated code please.

Comment: @gkaran89 Code updated, with your code corrected. Hope that helps but i doubt

Comment: what's the python3 version of this?