# How can I run code every x seconds inside a while loop?

Tags: python, while-loop

My problem simplified is that I want to send a different signal depending on the number X through  serial  to my connected Arduino board every 3 seconds however X should be updated more often than every three seconds.
Can I only update a specific part inside the while loop every 3 seconds and everything else normally?
Here is my python code in a nutshell:

```
while something:

 x= aChangingValue

 if x > 130 and x < 300:
  print('d')
  arduino.write('d'.encode())
 if x < 130:
  print('r')
  arduino.write('r'.encode())
 if x > 300:
  print('l')
  arduino.write('l'.encode())
```

I tried experimenting with the system time and threads but got nowhere. Other answers on relating topics also didn't work for me.

Comment: Not strictly the same problem, but you should find some good guidance in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18574562/python-schedule-repeating-multiple-threads) if you are ok using threads

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you've asked.

```py
import time

while something:

 x= aChangingValue

 if x > 130 and x < 300:
  print('d')
  arduino.write('d'.encode())
 if x < 130:
  print('r')
  arduino.write('r'.encode())
 if x > 300:
  print('l')
  arduino.write('l'.encode())
 time.sleep(3)
```

But remember that this is blocking for that sleep interval. Nothing else is happening in your program, which may work just fine, but depending on what else is happening, may not work how you imagine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I need X to update more than every 3 seconds so I can't use the sleep function.